# Rails 4 - Globally format to_json time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails API app and I am looking for a way to ensure all my serializers format their `to_json` time data in a specific way. I don't want to go through the code and write `created_at.to_s(:db)` but I can't seem to find a way around it.

Comment: I really like this gem:  https://github.com/basecamp/local_time.  It is from basecamp so you know its legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution in a monkey patch:

Add the following to `initializers/date_time.rb` does the trick nicely.

```
ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format = false

class DateTime
  def as_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
    if ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format
      strftime("%FT%T.%3NZ")
    else
      strftime("%F %T")
    end
  end
end

class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options = {})
    strftime('%F %T')
  end
end
```